# C# List<T> lambda Find then Modify elements

Tags: c#, lambda, generic-list

How would I go about doing this with a List using lambda

```
List<Foo> list....// create and add a bunch of Foo
int seconds = 100;

list.FindAll(x=>(x.Seconds == 0).Seconds = seconds) // yes I know that wont work...
```

In other words,  find all of the foo objects that Seconds == 0 and change the value to my local variable...

I don't want to loop the list...I am sure there is a way to do this with a simple lambda method...

Any help appreciated

Oneway

Answer (score 11):

Well, you *could* do:

```
list.FindAll(x => x.Seconds == 0)
    .ForEach(x => x.Seconds = seconds);
```

Personally I'd prefer an explicit loop for the side-effecting part though:

```
foreach (var x in list.Where(x => x.Seconds == 0))
{
    x.Seconds = seconds;
}
```

(I'm assuming this is a reference type, by the way. If it's a value type there are all kinds of other reasons why it wouldn't work.)

EDIT: You may wish to have a look at [Eric Lippert's thoughts on the matter too](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: Excellent...thanks...in this case the top method works and seems the cleanest...basically all I am doing/need to do is take all of the items whose seconds == 0 in quick move...Dig that extension method ForEach...thanks

Comment: In this case if I have indexes of the items to be modified, how should I write it?

Answer (score 1):

```
list.FindAll(x => x.Seconds == 0)
    .ForEach(x => x.Seconds = seconds);
```

I believe that the above does not compile.
`.ForEach(...)` returns void which can not be on the right-hand side of the `FindAll()` method.